# this keyword in ES6 classes, only works when enclosing inside a function?

Tags: javascript, this

```js
class App {
    states = {
        key: this,
        awsm: {
            another: function() {
                console.log(this);
            }
        }
    render() {
        console.log(this); // Here "this" point to the class 
        this.states.awsm.another(); // "this" will point to immediate enclosing object awsm, which is fine

        console.log(this.states.key); // but Here "this" should point immediate enclosing object/class but not happening
    }
}

const myapp = new App();
myapp.render();
```

In render function, `console.log(this)` point to class because class is its immediate binding,
simlarly `console.log(this.states.key)` should point to its immediate binding, which is states obj.
but that not happening.

**I think it will only look for its immediate binding, when this keyword is invoked from the inside of a function.** please tell me if i am correct

Comment: You've got some mismatched braces in your code. Can you please fix them and properly indent the code?

Comment: No, `this` in an object literal never points to the newly-constructed object. This has nothing to do with ES6 classes - `const obj = { key: this };` is the same (and `obj.key !== obj`).

Answer (score 1):

This syntax (called [public class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields)) is experimental and not officially part of JavaScript yet; its proposal in [TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) does say:

> ### Execution of initializer expressions
>
> ...
>
> **Scope**: The instance under construction is in scope as the `this` value inside the initializer expression.

So what you've written *should* work if this feature eventually gets implemented according to the current draft proposal, but right now, I wouldn't depend on it. The September 2020 way of achieving the same result is to assign to `this.x` inside the constructor.

That said, on my browser (Firefox 80.0.1) this works and shows `true`:

```js
class Foo {
  x = this;
  constructor() {
    document.write(this.x === this);
  }
}

new Foo();
```